# MongoDB Nested Documents Update with python

Tags: jquery, mongodb, python-2.7, python-3.x, pymongo

I am trying to aggregate some mongoDB records and have this returned value from an aggregation query with 1500 records:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "Year": 2016,
        "locationID": " WL 001",
        "Day": 25,
        "Hour": 12,
        "Month": 1
    },
    "temperature": 10.858749999999999,
    "pH": 0,
    "Conductivity": 2032.375
}
```

How do I insert the resulting values for `temperature`, `pH` and `Conductivity` such that the data to be inserted into the database have the following format?

```
{  
    "_id": {
        "Year": 2016,
        "locationID": " WL 001",
        "Day": 25,
        "Hour": 12,
        "Month": 1
    }, 
    "Readings": {
        "pH": { "value": 8.879 },
        "temperature": { "value": 16.81 },
        "Conductivity": { "value": 1084 }
    }
}
```

I have tried several approach but I can't seem to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an extra step in the aggregation pipeline, to project the data; in pymongo:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"
client = MongoClient(uri)
db = client['test']

db['test'].save({
    "_id": {
        "Year": 2016,
        "locationID": " WL 001",
        "Day": 25,
        "Hour": 12,
        "Month": 1
    },
    "temperature": 10.858749999999999,
    "pH": 0,
    "Conductivity": 2032.375
})


pipeline = [
{
    "$project": {
        '_id': '$_id',
        'Readings': {
            'pH': {'value': '$pH'},
            'temperature': {'value': '$temperature'},
            'Conductivity': {'value': '$Conductivity'}
        }
    }
},
]

result =  db['test'].aggregate(pipeline)
```